# Rust generates calls to __truncdfsf2, which it claims not to support?

Tags: rust, arduino, embedded, llvm

I'm writing some Rust code for an Atmega328. I understand that it does not have built in support for floats, so I will need to provide some sort of soft implementation of floating point routines that I want to use, like those found in [compiler-builtins](https://github.com/rust-lang/compiler-builtins). However, even after including compiler-builtins, I get the following:

```
quaternion.rs:54: undefined reference to `__truncdfsf2'
```

Looking at the page for compiler-builtins, I see that there are no plans to support `__truncdfsf2`, since apparently it "involves floating-point types ("f128", "f80" and complex numbers) that are not supported by Rust."

Can anyone help me understand why Rust/LLVM seems to be generating calls that Rust apparently doesn't support? And is there a way to go about solving this?

Here's my target.json for reference.

```
{
    "arch": "avr",
    "atomic-cas": false,
    "cpu": "atmega328",
    "data-layout": "e-P1-p:16:8-i8:8-i16:8-i32:8-i64:8-f32:8-f64:8-n8-a:8",
    "eh-frame-header": false,
    "exe-suffix": ".elf",
    "executables": true,
    "late-link-args": {
        "gcc": [
            "-lgcc"
        ]
    },
    "linker": "avr-gcc",
    "linker-is-gnu": true,
    "llvm-target": "avr-unknown-unknown",
    "max-atomic-width": 8,
    "no-default-libraries": false,
    "no-compiler-rt": true,
    "target-c-int-width": "16",
    "target-pointer-width": "16",
    "pre-link-args": {
    "gcc": [
      "-mmcu=atmega328",
      "-Wl,--as-needed"
    ]
  },
  "vendor": "unknown",
  "os": "none",
  "target-endian": "little"
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about Rust, but it seems to me that you are trying to do something with the toolchains that only support an ARM core on an AVR chip.  Atmega328 (and AVR chips) do not use gcc, it uses avr-gcc. For AVR, there is a [AVR-Rust project](https://github.com/avr-rust) that support the fork of Rust over AVR chips.

Comment: BTW, AVR chips (Arduino included) does support floating point by adding build flag `-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm`. See [AVR Libc](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#gaa3b98c0d17b35642c0f3e4649092b9f1) documentation for more details. It take up 1kB extra flash memory on Arduino.